# Is this site also good for miniature wargames questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I know this site is for board and card games but would you count miniature wargames into that group as well or are they separate kind of games? I mean games like Warhammer Fantasy Battle, Warhammer 40k etc.

Comment: First question that tests our feelings on this: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/274/using-quickshade-to-finish-miniatures-painting

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These games are not RPG, so I think they should be accepted.

Comment: I have the same feeling, but I wanted to get the opinion of others.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**,

Miniatures games are board games by any reasonable definition of the term.  This should include **all** facets of the hobby including

- preparation of figures
- terrain
- building an army
- tournament tips

Painting figures seems to have attracted some negative attention.  I do not feel this is warranted.  There is no way to separate painting from miniature games.  It is an integral part of the whole.

We support questions on:

- How to [store](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/storage) boardgames
- How to [Protect the surface](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/194/protecting-the-surface-of-your-board-games) of your boardgames
- [Deck Sleeves](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/793/worn-out-deck-of-cards)

These are all ancillary questions that have no direct bearing on the actual playing of the game and they have found a home on this site and received positive votes and quality answers.  On the other hand, painting miniatures often has a direct relation to playing the game.  There can be rules governing what colors can be used, in tournament play usually a good percentage of your final score is based on the painting and appearance of your army.

Answer (score 10):

I would count them as on-topic, as long as they are questions about *gaming* - questions about miniatures-painting are no more on topic than questions about corner-cutting for counters, or plexiglass systems for protecting boards (ie not).

After all, Blood Bowl is a board game played with minis from the same publisher.

Comment: A well made point, this should possibly be added to the site FAQ.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Comment: "Powertieke" posted a comment on http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/274/using-quickshade-to-finish-miniatures-painting : "This IS ontopic. If you can ask questions about game packaging, caring for pieces, then painting miniatures (For a game) is ontopic!" He does have a point. Even though I don't agree I have to admit that I cannot give a simple and clear definition of the boundary between taking care or your boardgame box/pieces and painting warhammer miniatures.

Comment: I don't think that taking care of your boardgame pieces or boxes should be on-topic, but it's a much smaller topic than miniature painting, so it will be a handful of questions.  Miniature painting risks bringing in the whole question of historical uniforms research!

Comment: Given a good enough tagging system, I don't care if we *do* bring in the whole uniform question.  (Not likely to happen unless we also allow questions on historical wargames.)  If Wargames.SE exists, wargames are clearly out of scope here, but that idea doesn't seem to be flooded with support at Area 51.  So possibly it's better to embrace wargames here.  (Certainly I don't want to rule out all mini painting questions, or we have to rule out mini questions for, say, Descent and Risk as well.  I agree that they're different from tactical questions... but how do they harm the site if allowed?)

Answer (score 6):

I would consider them on-topic. Otherwise, what exactly is the dividing line between Warhammer 40k and, say, Munchkin Quest? (That's the Munchkin board game, which doesn't really have a "board" as such, but a Carcassone-style growing map of tiles, and players and monsters running around on it.)

One possible answer to that is that Munchkin Quest-like games should also be excluded, but that game definitely feels like a board game.