# Are questions about Little Wars on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

In 1913, H.G. Wells wrote [Little Wars](http://ia700302.us.archive.org/9/items/littlewarsgamefo00well/littlewarsgamefo00well_bw.pdf), a book with a set of rules for a toy soldiers game. It is similar to [Kriegsspiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriegsspiel_%28wargame%29). I have a question about the rules  of it. Are questions about this game on-topic here? I checked the FAQ and this is what it said:

> - Be playable on or around a table
> - Have objective rules of play and win conditions
> - Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
> - Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

However, it is not played on a board, par se (see page 39). It is normally played in an area sometimes up to 18 feet wide. I normally play on a 8 foot wide (custom-made) table. Does this constitute a board game playable on a table, or is it off-topic here. The game fulfills every other requirement, but this one seemed stretching it. Are questions about Little Wars on-topic here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since questions on tabletop miniatures wargames are on-topic, (see, e.g., [this](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/753/1644)) Wells' 'Kriegspiel' is certainly so.

Whether this was the original miniatures wargame or whether various military staffs (or indeed small boys) beat him to it would be another question; but I think that one actually would be off-topic.)

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to makes sure. :)